# Why does PyCharm use 120 Character Lines even though PEP8 Specifies 79?

Tags: python, pycharm, pep8

PEP8 clearly specifies 79 characters, however, PyCharm defaults to 120 and gives me the warning "PEP8: line too long (... > 120 characters)".

Did previous versions of PEP8 use 120 and PyCharm not update its PEP8 checker? I couldn't find any previous versions of the PEP8 Guide, however, I can easily find previous version of the PEP8 Python scripts.

I'm starting a new Python project and I'm not sure which to use.

References:

http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: if you want to be pep-8 compliant then the answer is in your link

Comment: there might be an undesirable global user experience variable that pep8 is not accountable to (and really shouldn't be)...but PyCharm is.

Comment: I don't see why PEP-8 should not be accountable to developers for influencing their experience. There's a popular SO answers that says there's no obvious benefit for having code lines longer than 80. I can't remember a statement that's more obviously wrong.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

PyCharm is built on top of IntelliJ.  IntelliJ has a default line length of 120 characters.

This is probably because you can't fit a common Java name like: `@annotated public static MyObjectFactoryFactory enterpriseObjectFactoryFactoryBuilderPattern {` in a mere 80 character line. (I'm poking fun, but Java names do tend to be longer by convention).

The pep8 checker is configurable, so you can specify a better max line length - like 79 characters.

The error is misleading because the pep8 checker formats the text with something like `"PEP8: line too long(... > %s characters)" % max_line_setting`.  So it's using the pep8 checker, with a specific configuration, not claiming that pep8 specifies a 120 character line.

Comment: I think Intellij Python plugin IS Pycharm for Intellij. But I wouldn't say that Pycharm is built on top of Intellij, which is the highend product from JetBrains.

Comment: @Apero According to the [JetBrains blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2013/10/pycharm-3-0-community-edition-source-code-now-available/) "The code is all there on GitHub, ready for you to play with. It’s not a separate project but rather part of the main IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition project". IntelliJ is just their Java IDE, and comes in both a free-as-in-beer community edition and a paid version with additional enterprisey features. You can purchase a version of PyCharm with similar features as well.

Comment: This is a known issue they are working to correct: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16078

Answer (score 8):

If you want to remove the limit warning altogether you can take the following steps:

1. In PyCharm, click File > Settings
2. In the project settings section, click Editor > Inspections
3. In the list that appears, expand Python
4. Under Python, scroll down and click "PEP8 coding style violation"
5. Click the + button next to "Ignore errors" in the bottom right
6. Type out E501 and click Apply and/or OK

Sources:

- http://iambigblind.blogspot.com/2013/02/configuring-pep8py-support-in-pycharm-27.html
- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205816889-Disable-individual-PEP8-style-checking-line-length-

Comment: Ignoring this PEP8 violation however, is generally bad practice as it can mean your code is less readable in most circumstances.

Answer (score -5):

AFAIK, PEP8 has never allowed 120 characters, but not everyone follows PEP8. 
To answer your question: stay under 80 characters, both from common courtesy and good sense.

Comment: But PyCharm claims 120 is PEP8. Why are they misleading people?

Comment: I'll defer to @munkhd's answer, since I don't use PyCharm. (stick with emacs, everything will work much better...)

Comment: From PEP-8 (but I code up to 120 chars, and occasionally violate that limit too): "... Some teams strongly prefer a longer line length. For code maintained exclusively or primarily by a team that can reach agreement on this issue, it is okay to increase the **line length limit up to 99 characters** ..."